# Angular fire auth can't get user data from store after page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, rxjs

I'm using Firebase Authentication, email and password sign up.
My **login** function is working like a charm, I'm calling:

```
await setPersistence(this.auth, browserLocalPersistence);
```

after login, at it works. I'm saving the user data to firestore after creating a new user, that works too.

**My problem is:**

In my `auth.service.ts` I'm trying to get the user document based on the **auth.currentUser**, I checked it in devtools, that the persistence is working properly, I get the currentUser from firebase always, when I need to.

So I'm doing this:

```
this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  console.log('FIRE AUTH ON AUTH STATE CHANGED RUNNING', user);
  if (user) {
    this.user$ = of(user).pipe(
      switchMap(async user => {
        try {
          const res = await getDoc(doc(this.db, 'users', user.uid));
          console.log(res.data());
          return res.data() as FireUser;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return null;
        }
      })
    );
  } else {
    this.user$ = of(null);
  }
});
```

Right after the login it works, but after I do refresh (and I still get the currentUser properly), the function just stops, without any errors, or anything. It just won't go inside the switchMap.

**I'm logging the currentUser right in the start of onAuthStateChanged and I get it's value correctly.**.

(Also tried it like this):

```
onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, user => {
  console.error('USER IS', user);
  if (user) {
    this.user$ = docData(
      doc(this.db, 'users', user.uid)
    ) as Observable<FireUser>;
  } else {
    this.user$ = of(null);
  }
});
```

Displaying the user$ Observable data in a component like this:
TS:

```
user$ = this.fireAuthService.user$;
```

HTML:

```
  <div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
    <pre>
     {{ user | json }}
   </pre>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**So my solution is (based on @Werner7's answer):**

```
  private userSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<FireUser>(null);

  get user$(): Observable<FireUser> {
    return this.userSubject$.asObservable();
  }

    onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, async user => {
      console.error('USER IS', user);
      if (user) {
        this.userSubject$.next(
          (await getDoc(doc(this.db, 'users', user.uid))).data() as FireUser
        );
      } else {
        this.userSubject$.next(null);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do using behaviorSubject which I like because it's a little more dynamic.

```
export class AuthService {

  private readonly user$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel | null>(null);

  private _internalUserTmp: UserModel;

 public get internalUserTemp(): UserModel {
    return this._internalUserTmp;
  }
  private set internalUserTemp(value: UserModel) {
    this._internalUserTmp = value;
  }

  get currentUser(): Observable<UserModel | null> {
    return this.user$.asObservable();
  }

constructor(
    private readonly auth: Auth,
    private readonly firestore: Firestore,
    private readonly functions: Functions) {
    onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, user => {
      // console.log("State Chaned: ", user);
      this.retrieveUserData(user);
      auth.currentUser?.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult => {
        // console.log(idTokenResult);
        if (!!idTokenResult.claims.superAdmin) {
          this._isSuperAdmin$.next(true);
          this._isAdmin$.next(true);
        } else if(!!idTokenResult.claims.admin){
          this._isAdmin$.next(true);
          this._isSuperAdmin$.next(false);
        }else {
          this._isAdmin$.next(false);
          this._isSuperAdmin$.next(false);
        }

      })
    });
    this.user$.subscribe(user => {
      this.internalUserTemp = user as UserModel;
    });
}

private async retrieveUserData(user: User | null): Promise<void> {
    if (!user) {
      this.user$.next(null);
      return;
    }
    if (user.email === undefined || null || '') {
      this.user$.next(null);
      return;
    }
    await this.getUserDataByEmail(user.email ? user.email : '').subscribe(
      userData => {
        this.user$.next(userData);
      }
    );
  }

getUserDataByEmail(email: string) {
    return docData(doc(this.firestore, "users/", email));
  }
```

Then I use UserModel which structured like this..

```
export class UserModel extends BaseModel {
    uid?: string | null;
    auth_id?: string | null;
    adminReview?: boolean | null;
//...

constructor(config?: UserModel) {
  super();
  config = Object.assign({}, config);
  this.uid = config.uid;
  this.auth_id = config.auth_id;
  this.adminReview = config.adminReview;
//...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, updated the question with a solution based like this, so I accepted your answer